# Show one window while opening multiple window

Tags: javascript, focus, window.open

here is the example Code in Javascript, i would like to open 3 window, but wish to define which one window should be seen or shown.

```
var x = window.open("http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker", "one");

var y = window.open("https://www.google.de/", "two");

var z = window.open("https://www.youtube.com/?gl=DE&hl=de", "three");

x.focus();
```

I tought using focus would show this website jabra, but won'show up, it will show only in the last code of z-window "youtube".

Please enlighten me how to define it, that i can select which window shall be shown while openening of all multiple window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(() => x.focus());
```

Comment: Does it just do nothing, or are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: it open truly three window, but show in the third z window, also Youtube. And I looked in Inspect element, there isn't even error.

Comment: Maybe it's browser dependent. It's working for me with Firefox. I have a Plunker to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/u7WibVSQj9OPr1BbJFMp?p=preview

Comment: wow, you're right, it work truly good in your Plunker. I'm astonished. I wrote this in easy datafile like test.html then written HTML with script this above code and then put in Browser. it work but not like yours in Plunker. I am using Chrome.